# Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

Tags: lebesgue-integral, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I was studying the "Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations" and I have fully understood the proof to it except for one little step. The problem is:

$f$ is a contineous function in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and we assume that for $x_0 \in \Omega$ $f$ holds $f(x_0)\neq0$. Since $f$ is contineous for a small $\delta>0$ there exists a neighborhood $V_\delta$ with $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in V_\delta(x_0)$. Than we define the function $\psi(x)$

$\psi(x) := \begin{cases}
(\| x-x_0\|-\delta)^2 \cdot (\| x-x_0\|-\delta)^2 & \text{for } x\in V_\delta(x_0),\\
0 & \, \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

The problem now is, that in the book I am learning from the author states that $\psi\in L^1(\Omega)$ without any proof or calculation. Why is it so that $\psi\in L^1(\Omega)$? Do I need to show $\int_\Omega\psi(x)\text{ d}x<\infty$ or is there any easier way to show that.

I would appreciate any further help :)

Comment: what do you mean by $(x-x_0-\delta)^2$? Here, $x,x_0\in \Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ and $\delta>0$ is a real number, so the difference and the square aren't well-defined.

Comment: It is well defined, because $x-x_0<\delta$.

Comment: tell me how do you subtract a number from a vector? What is $(1,2,3)-5$?

Comment: omg, now I feel stupid

Comment: but i can define a neigbourhood for every coordinate and then it should be possible.

Comment: I'm going to ask you one last time: how do you define the subtraction of a number from a vector? Did you instead mean to write $(\|x-x_0\|-\delta)^2$? If yes, then please make the corresponding edits, otherwise, your question is meaningless.

Comment: Yes i meant to write $(\| x-x_0\|-\delta)^2$. I corrected the question.

Comment: In this case, you have a bounded function which vanishes outside a set of finite measure. Hence, it is integrable

Comment: Thank you very much